# How do I get wildcards from nested referenes with cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get all the wildcards when something is writen at my database and send a push notification

```
const device_token = admin.database().ref(`/fatherNode/here_is_my_wildcard/device_token`).once('value');
const productName = admin.database().ref(`/fatherNode/here_is_my_wildcard/productname`).once('value');
```

below of this I have a promise, that gets the values of this two

```
  return Promise.all([device_token, productName]).then(results => {

        const devicetoken = results[0].val();
        const productName = results[1].val();

...
```

my database structure is like this

```
fatherNode
|_________ wildcard
          |___device_token: random device token (String)
          |___productName: random product name (String)
```

Now, I will have more than 1 wildcard, so when my onWrite function triggers , I want to get all the wildcards in order to send notifications to each device, or at least, the last one who triggered the onWrite function

Comment: Have you read the documentation on realtime database triggers?  It explains how to get wildcard values from each invocation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: but how do I access to wildcards outside a trigger function ? with once or on ?